# Rotations Matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

You are given a square matrix A of dimensions NxN. You need to apply the below given 3 operations on matrix A.

Rotation: It is represented as R S where S is an integer in {90, 180, 270, 360, 450, ...} which denotes the number of degrees to rotate. You need to rotate matrix A by angle S in the clockwise direction. The angle of rotation(S) will always be in multiples of 90 degrees.

Update: It is represented as U X Y Z. In initial matrix A (as given in input), you need to update the element at row index X and column index Y with value Z.
After the update, all the previous rotation operations have to be applied to the updated initial matrix.

Querying: It is represented as Q K L. You need to print the value at row index K and column index L of the matrix A.

This was my question. Here is what I have done so far:

```
def ReadMatrix():
    matrix = []
    for i in range(int(input())):
        row = [int(j) for j in input().split()]
        matrix.append(row) 
    return matrix

def RotateMatrix(matrix, degrees):
    n = len(matrix[0])
    rotations = (degrees // 90) % 4
    for r in range(rotations):
        temp_matrix = []
        for i in range(n):
            column = [row[i] for row in matrix]
            column.reverse()
            temp_matrix.append(column)
        matrix = temp_matrix
    return matrix

matrix = ReadMatrix()
rotation = 0

while True:
    line = input().split()
    if line[0] == "-1":
        break;
    elif line[0] == "R":
        rotation += int(line[1])
        matrix = RotateMatrix(matrix, int(line[1]))
    elif line[0] == "U":
         matrix[int(line[1])][int(line[2])] = int(line[3])
         matrix = RotateMatrix(matrix, rotation)
    elif line[0] == "Q":
        print(matrix[int(line[1])][int(line[2])]) 
    else:
        print(line[0])
        exit(1)
```

I am getting correct output for this input:

```
2
1 2
3 4
R 90
Q 0 0
Q 0 1
R 90
Q 0 0
U 0 0 6
Q 1 1
-1
```

But I am not getting correct output for this input

```
2
5 6
7 8
R 90
Q 0 1
R 270
Q 1 1
R 180
U 0 0 4
Q 0 0
-1
```

The output I am getting for the second input is `5 8 5` but the correct output is  `5 8 8`.

Comment: WHY ARE WE USING CAPITALS?

Answer (score 2):

You are very close.  Of course you knew that.  :)

The problem you are having is that you are not explicitly following the instruction for the Update action.  It says you should apply the update to the *original matrix* and then re-rotate it.  You are applying the update to the *already rotated matrix* and then re-rotating it.

So.  How do we fix?  We need to maintain a *copy* of the original matrix for such purposes and then use that as the basis of our Update command.  Python has a built in `copy()` command which will work fine in this case because the thing you are copying are lists of integer types (not reference variables).

Consider capturing your original matrix like this:

```
matrix = ReadMatrix()
orig_matrix = matrix.copy()
```

Then you can update that as needed and pass in that updated matrix into your re-rotation operation.

If you want to watch the play-by-play to verify what is going on, I suggest adding a little print statement to the end of your loop that you can comment out when satisfied that all is good...

```
...
else:
    print(line[0])
    sys.exit(1)
print('matrix:', matrix)
print('orig  :', orig_matrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
exit=1
ar=[]
pr=[]
up=0
pu=0
def array_rot(rang, ar):
    for k in range(rang):
            for i in range(a//2):
                c=''
                for j in range(i, a-i-1):
                    temp=ar[i][j]
                    ar[i][j]=ar[a-1-j][i]
                    ar[a-1-j][i]=ar[a-1-i][a-1-j]
                    ar[a-1-i][a-1-j]=ar[j][a-1-i]
                    ar[j][a-1-i]=temp
    return ar
for i in range(a):
    inp=input().split()
    ar.append(inp)
while(exit!=-1):
    q=input()
    r=q.split()
    if(q[0]=='R'):
        rang=int(r[1])//90
        up=up+rang
        pu=rang+pu
        ar=array_rot(rang, ar)
    elif(q[0]=='U'):
        ran=0
        while(up%4!=0):
            ran=ran+1 
            up=up+1
        ar=array_rot(ran, ar)
        ar[int(r[1])][int(r[2])]=r[3]
        ar=array_rot(pu,pr)
        pu=0
    elif(q[0]=='Q'):
        print(ar[int(r[1])][int(r[2])])
    elif(r[0]=='-1'):
        exit=-1
```

Comment: this will work. but sorry for using meaning less variables.bye..:)

Answer (score 0):

```
 a = int(input())
 matrix = []
 rotation = 0

for i in range(a):
    row = [int(j) for j in input().split()]
    matrix.append(row) 
orig_matrix = matrix.copy() 

def RotateMatrix(matrix, degrees):
    n = len(matrix[0])
    rotations = (degrees // 90) % 4

    for r in range(rotations):
        temp_matrix = []

        for i in range(n):
            column = [row[i] for row in matrix]
            column.reverse()
            temp_matrix.append(column)

        matrix = temp_matrix
    return matrix
    
while True:
    line = input().split()
    if line[0] == "-1":
        break;

    elif line[0] == "R":
        rotation += int(line[1])
        matrix = RotateMatrix(matrix, int(line[1]))

    elif line[0] == "U":
         orig_matrix[int(line[1])][int(line[2])] = int(line[3])
         matrix = RotateMatrix(orig_matrix, rotation)

    elif line[0] == "Q":
        print(matrix[int(line[1])][int(line[2])])

    else:
        print("Error: unexpected command '" + line[0] + "'")
        exit(1)

your code is fine. but miss this condition
Update: It is represented as U X Y Z. In initial matrix A (as given in input), you need to update the element at row index X and column index Y with value Z. **After the update, all the previous rotation operations have to be applied to the *updated initial matrix*.**
```

Comment: Hi, could you add a little introduction or explanation to your answer. A code only answer can be a bit confusing.